# Page Break and Alt Tag not working in Itext7 html2pdf

Tags: alt, page-break, html2pdf, itext7

I am trying the sample code as explained in the documentation page

http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-examples/converting-html-pdf/pdfhtml-accessible-pdf-creation

However, when i generate pdf, The alt tags are not set and hence pdf accessibility checker complains. I also found out that page break does't work from the given sample html page. Can someone help me to solve these two issues? My POM.xml has the following dependencies. I have created the exact files and copied the code as mentioned in the above article.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
  <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.2</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
  <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
 </dependency>

<repository>
   <id>itext</id>
   <name>iText Repository - releases</name>
   <url>https://repo.itextsupport.com/releases</url>
</repository>
```

Thanks

SGK

Comment: I tested with iText 7.0.3 and html2pdf 1.0.1, and I clearly see the `/Alt` entry in the structure tree when I add an image (I just checked a PDF I created last week). I don't know about page breaks (haven't tested them; don't have the time right now), but maybe it's best if you contact iText Software directly, because 7.0.3 and pdfHTML 1.0.1 are about to be released. My bet is that `/Alt` will be fixed, but you should ask iText Software if page break is being fixed too.

Comment: Thanks Bruno for your response.  I appreciate your help. How do you get the 1.0.1 version of the html2pdf library from the repo ? I couldn't find it on the official repository https://repo.itextsupport.com/releases/com/itextpdf/html2pdf/

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not released yet. I'm working with an early access version.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. I tried with snapshot release. it works including page breaks. Thanks a lot for the direction.- SGK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for the page-break-after CSS property has been added in pdfHTML v1.0.1

The absence of the /alt tags was a bug in v1.0.0 and is fixed in v1.0.1

(Posting this as answer for the sake of visibility, since this question has popped up here and there before).